# How I can load only modules in angular 8 using lazy loading

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular8, angular-routing, angular-router

I have question about the lazy loading. Using *Augury* to detect my router tree structure.

[image]

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
       path: 'reservation',
          loadChildren: () => import('./modules/reservations/reservations.module').then(mod => mod.ReservationsModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'add',
        loadChildren: () => import('./modules/add-autopoint/add-autopoint.module').then(mod => mod.AddAutopointModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'availability',
        loadChildren: () => import('./modules/availability/availability.module').then(mod => mod.AvailabilityModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'archive',
        loadChildren: () => import('./modules/archive/archive.module').then(mod => mod.ArchiveModule)
      },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: '/reservation', pathMatch: 'full' },
    ]
  }
];
```

*Example module routing*

**reservation-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ReservationComponent },
  { path: 'summary/:id', component: SummaryComponent, resolve: { summary: AtplSummaryResolver, notes: AtplNotesResolver } }
];
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FilterPipe,
    LoaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    SharedModule,
    NgxMatSelectSearchModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    AddAutopointModule,
    ArchiveModule,
    ReservationsModule,
    AvailabilityModule,
    Ng2LoadingSpinnerModule.forRoot({}),
    NavigationModule
  ],
  providers: [
    CommonService,
    AlertService,
    ListService,
    LoaderService,
    MenuService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Is it normal to load these components at first or I'm doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I remove these modules :

*AddAutopointModule*,

*ArchiveModule*,

*ReservationsModule*,

*AvailabilityModule*

from my app.module.ts i fixed my problem with the lazy loading

[image]

Answer (score 2):

common services, components, pipes ..., used only in lazy-loaded modules, should be grouped in Shared Module, and this module is imported only in these lazy-loaded modules. other components, services and other things needed in the whole app (like authorization services or directives, layout components or services...) put it in a Core module imported in the App module. The Core module (and other modules imported in the App module) should be as lightweight as possible.